# gRPC and MVC in same ASP.NET Core 3.0 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, grpc

I am building out small, single purpose micro-services that require access via gRPC and Rest. We are implementing on ASP.NET Core 3.0. I realize this is pretty fresh stuff and have been looking for some reasonably complete reference implementations that demonstrate how to get this done.

I have a small .NET Service (Business Logic) call it IOrders. Now I want to wire up both gRPC and MVC (HTTP) against this back end service.

Any examples, github repos, blogs to follow or look around in would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet) for the gRPC for the version that shipped with Asp.net Core 3 preview 3.

Comment: This is the implementation guide of gRPC in ASP.NE Core 3,1 - [link](https://www.yogihosting.com/grpc-aspnet-core/) . You will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same issue. I am runing.NET Core 3.0 and Grpc.AspNetCore Version 2.23.1. The biggest problem was to start it without SSL (not recommended for prod environments). Using certificate i found this [github Secure_gRpc](https://github.com/damienbod/Secure_gRpc/) to be nice example.
Running without ssl for dev environments could be achieved in this way.

Program.cs file. Key aspects is to set HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2. I also removed certificate just to get it running. Uncomment next line to use SSL and certificate

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }


    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = null;

                    options.ListenLocalhost(8008, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                        listenOptions.UseHttps(adapterOptions =>
                        {
                            adapterOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.NoCertificate;
                            adapterOptions.ServerCertificate = null;
                        });
                        //listenOptions.UseHttps("<path to .pfx file>", "<certificate password>");
                    });
                });

            });
}
```

Startup.cs is pretty straightforward. It is very important to remember if you modify Startup.cs file order of added services is very important. If it doesnt work try other order and/or find official documentation.

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc((options => { options.EnableDetailedErrors = true; }));
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);            
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();

        });

    }
}
```